# Sharepoint Online SOAP request to create List item via Excel VBA

Tags: xml, vba, soap, sharepoint-online, winhttprequest

I need to programmatically add a list item to a SharePoint Online list, exclusively from the VBA environment in an Excel workbook.

My current list has one column:  Title
(I added the below list item manually in my web browser)

[image: The list I'd like to add to with VBA]

Current VBA test sub below.  My expectation is that this would create a new list object called "PLEASE WORK":

```
Sub testList()
    Dim sharepointUrl As String: sharepointUrl = "https://redacted.sharepoint.com/sites/redacted/"
    Dim strListGUID As String: strListGUID = "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"
    
    Dim objXMLHTTP As WinHttpRequest
    Set objXMLHTTP = New WinHttpRequest
    
    'XML batch element to be inserted into SOAP body <updates>
    Dim strUpdate As String
    strUpdate = "<Batch OnError=""Continue"" ListVersion=""1"">"
    strUpdate = strUpdate & "<Method ID=""1"" Cmd=""New"">"
    'strUpdate = strUpdate & "<Field Name='ID'>New</Field>"
    strUpdate = strUpdate & "<Field Name=""Title"">""PLEASE WORK""</Field>"
    strUpdate = strUpdate & "2006-1-11T09:15:30Z</Field>"
    strUpdate = strUpdate & "</Method>"
    strUpdate = strUpdate & "</Batch>"

    'SOAP body
    Dim strSoapBody As String
    strSoapBody = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "<soap12:Body>"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "<UpdateListItems xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "<listName>" & strListGUID & "</listName>"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "<updates>" & strUpdate & "</updates>"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "</UpdateListItems>"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "</soap12:Body>"
    strSoapBody = strSoapBody & "</soap12:Envelope>"
    'Debug.Print strSoapBody
    
    objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", sharepointUrl & "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
    objXMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    objXMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strSoapBody)
    
    objXMLHTTP.Send strSoapBody
    
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        'Do something with response
        Debug.Print "200"
    End If
    
    Debug.Print objXMLHTTP.ResponseText 'empty response
    
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code runs without error and returns an empty ResponseText, with no changes visible to the Sharepoint list.  Any ideas how to debug this?

I noticed earlier that if I visit the URL [sharepointUrl & "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"], I am given some documentation (this is for UpdateListItems)

```
UpdateListItems
Test
The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.
SOAP 1.1
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted.sharepoint.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>string</listName>
      <updates>string</updates>
    </UpdateListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <UpdateListItemsResult>string</UpdateListItemsResult>
    </UpdateListItemsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
SOAP 1.2
The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted.sharepoint.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>string</listName>
      <updates>string</updates>
    </UpdateListItems>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <UpdateListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <UpdateListItemsResult>string</UpdateListItemsResult>
    </UpdateListItemsResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I am not sure how to best make use of this.  I used info from the SOAP 1.2 example for the VBA.

EDIT:  I commented out the line `strUpdate = strUpdate & "2006-1-11T09:15:30Z</Field>"` in the XML batch element.  The VBA still runs without error, but now I have ResponseText coming through from the WinHttpRequest obj with an XML error message containing this:

Server was unable to process request. ---> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: Maybe look at this:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255264/sharepoint-api-and-vba-access-denied

Comment: I was looking at that one yesterday!  However I got stuck at the first part: stsURL = "https://[get this URL using the GetUserRealm.srf endpoint]/adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport"
I am in very unfamiliar territory, here..

Comment: Sorry I don't really know anything about using the SharePoint SOAP endpoints...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem:

```vb
strUpdate = strUpdate & "<Field Name=""Title"">""PLEASE WORK""</Field>"
strUpdate = strUpdate & "2006-1-11T09:15:30Z</Field>"
```

Comment: Good catch-- thank you.

New problem.  Response text non-empty now.  This is part of it:  "Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Access is denied. "